# Error term of the prime number theorem on GRH?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that under GRH we have 
$$
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq n \leq X \\ n \equiv a (q) }} \Lambda(n) = \frac{X}{\phi(q)} + O(X^{1/2} (\log X^2)). 
$$
From this I would like to deuce a abound for $E$ where
$$
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq p \leq X \\ p \equiv a (q) }} 1 = \frac{\sum_{\substack{1 \leq p \leq X  }} 1}{\phi(q)} + E.
$$
How can I achieve this? (Basically I am interested in the error term to the above form of Siegel-Walfisz under GRH) thank you.

PS Here $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function

PPS I first thought maybe I can obtain a bound of type $E \ll X^{1/2}(\log X)^2$ by partial summation but it doesn't seem to be the working.. I would appreciate any comments on what is the correct bound for $E$ under GRH. There are a lot of information with log weight but I couldn't find any without it.. Thank you.

Comment: It is completely obvious that $E = O(X^{1/2} (\log X)^2)+ O(X^{1/2} (\log X)^2)=O(X^{1/2} (\log X)^2)$

Comment: @reuns I'm actually not seeing this... Could you please explain a little more by any chance?

Comment: "completely obvious" is apparently a rather subjective formulation. I am honest enough to admit, that for me it is not at all obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$\sum_{n \le x} f(n)=O(x^a \log^b x)$$ then $$\sum_{n \le x} \frac{f(n)}{\log n} =\frac1{\log x} \sum_{n \le x} f(n)+\sum_{n \le x-1}( \sum_{m \le n} f(m)) (\frac1{\log n}-\frac1{\log (n+1)} )$$
$ \frac1{\log n}-\frac1{\log (n+1)} = \frac{\log(n+1)-\log n}{\log n \log (n+1)} = O(\frac1{n \log^2 n})$
$$ = O( x^a \log^{b-1} x+\sum_{n \le x} n^{a-1} \log^{b-2} n) =O( x^a \log^{b-1} x+\log^{b-2} x\sum_{n \le x} n^{a-1} )=O(x^a \log^{b-1} x)$$

Doing it with $f(n) = \Lambda(n) 1_{n \equiv a \bmod q}- \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\phi(q)}$ and using $\sum_{p^k \le x, k \ge 2}  \frac1k (1_{p^k\equiv a \bmod q}-\frac1{\phi(q)})  = O(x^{1/2})$ gives the result

Comment: Ah, the trick was to do summation by parts with the relevant *mean zero* function. +1